# GARCH(1,1) residuals are not homoskedastic

Tags: time-series, modeling, garch, volatility-forecasting

Given the following simulated [GARCH(1, 1) process](http://faculty.washington.edu/rons/wlb/node13.html):

```
omega = 0.9
a1 = 0.2
b1 = 0.6
mu = 5
errors = [0] # trivial case 
stds = [0] # trivial case 
series = []
for i in range(10000):
    std = math.sqrt(omega + a1 * errors[-1]**2 + b1 * stds[-1]**2)
    stds.append(std)
    noise = gauss(0, 1)
    error = std * noise
    errors.append(error)
    series.append(mu + error)
```

This is what the series looks like:

[image: Time series plot of a GARCH(1, 1) process]

Fitting a GARCH(1, 1) model:

```
model = arch_model(series, rescale=True)
fit = model.fit()
fit.summary()
```

[image: Results of model fitting]

From the summary above, it can be seen that the algorithm is able to correctly estimate the mu, alpha, beta and omega parameters that were originally used to create the time series.

However when I run the LM test the residuals are not homoskedastic:

```
fit.arch_lm_test()

ARCH-LM Test
H0: Residuals are homoskedastic.
ARCH-LM Test
H1: Residuals are conditionally heteroskedastic.
Statistic: 2007.3327
P-value: 0.0000
Distributed: chi2(38)
```

If I plot the ACF of the residuals it looks like white noise...:

```
plot_acf(fit.resid)
```

[image]

...but the acf plot of squared residuals tells a different story:

```
plot_acf(np.square(fit.resid))
```

[image]

Is there any reason why the residuals of this GARCH(1, 1) model are still heteroskedastic?

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

In a GARCH model
\begin{aligned}
y_t &= \mu_t + u_t, \\
\mu_t &= \dots \text{(e.g. a constant or an ARMA equation without the term $u_t$)}, \\
u_t &= \sigma_t \varepsilon_t, \\
\sigma_t^2 &= \omega + \alpha_1 u_{t-1}^2 + \dotsc + \alpha_s u_{t-s}^2 + \beta_1 \sigma_{t-1}^2 + \dotsc + \beta_r \sigma_{t-r}^2, \\
\varepsilon_t &\sim i.i.d(0,1), \\
\end{aligned}
the assumption of i.i.d.'ness is made for standardized errors/shocks/innovations $\varepsilon_t$. Raw (unstandardized) residuals $\hat u_t$ are estimates of model errors $u_t$, and these are characterized by a GARCH-type autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity, as can be seen from the equations above. Are you perhaps analyzing $\hat u_t$ instead of $\hat\varepsilon_t$? This could explain the finding of autocorrelation in their squares (but lack of autocorrelation in their levels).